# Angular 8.3.2: Convert ArrayBuffer to Float32Array

Tags: typescript

In a client I'm getting a websocket message from server:

```js
this.wsSubscription = this.webSocket.createObservableSocket ("ws://localhost:8080")
      .subscribe (
        data => 
        {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data);
          reader.onload = () => {
            
            var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
            console.log (arrayBuffer);
            //Convert array buffer to Float32 array
        }
```

How should I convert "arrayBuffer" to Float32Array ?
I tried:
fArray = new Float32Array  (arrayBuffer);

but got syntax error.

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```js
this.wsSubscription = this.webSocket.createObservableSocket ("ws://localhost:8080")
  .subscribe (
    data => 
    {
         var bufferPromise = data.arrayBuffer();
         data.arrayBuffer().then (buffer =>{
         var arr32 = new Float32Array (buffer);
    }
```